# can't access property "name", test[0] is undefined

Tags: reactjs

When trying to access the key of an object from a specific array, this error occurs. If you access the array test [0], it shows an object, if you access a specific key test [0] .name, an error is generated. Tell me what is the problem?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {



    render() {
        const {test} = this.props;
        console.log(test[0].name);
        ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
[
  {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
        "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
        "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
    }...
]
```

Comment: Is the data from props coming from an API call originally? If yes, you can maybe do `null` check before accessing that element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Put a null check condition for actual value and to avoid rendering errors.

```
const {test} = this.props;
 let name = test && test[0].name;
 console.log(name);
```